# Run bash script from php

Tags: bash, scripts, php

I want to run a shell script within a php webpage to check some processes running on my system (Ubuntu 12.04). Googleing I've found about `shell_exec()` but I can't manage to run the script when loading php.

This is the php code I use.

```
$output = shell_exec('./dirlist.bash');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

and the piece of html I get

```
<pre></pre>
```

Also tried `$output = shell_exec('sudo -u www-data ./dirlist.bash');`

*dirlist.bash* does *ls -l*     (just for testing script and shell_exec)

I think it is not a permission problem. Running directory grants write and execute privileges for all users (I should be careful here).

```
drwxrwxrwx  4 meteo meteo 4096 mar 11 15:20 RAMS
```

User www-data has been added to sudoers file in case it was needed

```
www-data ALL = (meteo) NOPASSWD: /home/meteo/www/RAMS/dirlist.bash
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here unless they are directly related to administering your system. I suggest you ask on [so], but your problem is almost certainly that you are using relative paths (`./dirlist_bash`). And for the love of all that's fluffy, **remove www-data from sudoers!**

Comment: You are right, I will move to Stack Overflow. And as you ask so kindly I will remove www-data :-)

Comment: Hi, now using absolute path it is running fine, thank you very much.

Comment: can you post a link to your question on SO here in the comments for others who follow? thanks!

Comment: There it is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24206921/709777)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably need to chdir to the correct directory before calling the script. This way you can ensure what directory your script is "in" before calling the shell command.

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/my/path/');
$output = shell_exec('./script.sh var1 var2');
chdir($old_path);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Comment: This has a disturbing similarity to [a block of code on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php). Give credit.